# Actionscript 3 Text below image in TextArea.htmlText

Tags: actionscript-3, textarea

I would like to display an image and a text below it in a TextArea but I can't figure out why the text is displayed on the right of the image.
Here is my code :

```
var textArea:TextArea = new TextArea();

var urlLdr:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLdr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
urlLdr.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
urlLdr.load(new URLRequest("myText.html"));//the file only contains the string "Test image" with no html tag

function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
    var str:String = event.target.data as String;

    htmlTextArea.htmlText = "<p><img src='myImage.jpg'/> </p>";
    htmlTextArea.htmlText += "<p>"+str+"</p>";
    addChild(htmlTextArea);
}
```

And I get :

[image]

I tried by adding the tag < br/ > , and \n in the htmlText between the image and the text but it only makes the text be written lower on the right.
With :

```
htmlTextArea.htmlText = "<p><img src='myImage.jpg'/> </p><br/><br/><br/>";
```

I get :

[image]

So, how to write the text below the image?

Comment: Probably drop bounding `<p>` tags and just have `<img src="..."><br />Test image`

Comment: Nope, I get the same result without the <p> tags.

Comment: `TextField` html image support is very rudimentary and full of bugs. I've never found a solution to this particular problem, and it's plagued me many times. If you are using AIR you can use `HTMLLoader` which is a full WebKit renderer. Otherwise, the only alternative I know of is to separate your text from your image into different display objects (ex, use a `Bitmap` above a `TextField`) and control the layout yourself.

Comment: I don't use AIR so I'll separate the image from the text. Thanks.